# Magento 1.9 Product Image Upload Console Error

Tags: product, image

**Console Error :**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden)
>
> VM262:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at XMLHttpRequest.UploadFile.xhr.onreadystatechange (965258ac47073d26e0b556877b7e343b.js:23521)
>   UploadFile.xhr.onreadystatechange @
>   965258ac47073d26e0b556877b7e343b.js:23521

**note**: all file persmission set.

Answer (score 1):

Appears to be a bug in 1.9.4.5.

```
app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Links.php
app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Samples.php
```

To fix this, copy the files to app/code/local/ and remove ->addSessionParam() that adds ?SID= to the URL.